# Laptop GPU Noise

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, cooling, quiet-computing, nvidia

Around two years ago, I bought a new laptop with a GPU that can support applications going beyond regular office software. Over time, it turned out to not have been a great choice of hardware. Even when using simple programs, the GPU has a noisy fan running at higher speed. It is like sitting in front of an aircraft engine.

Now, my employer offered to buy a new work laptop, and unlike the above described private machine I really need this device to be quiet. It is okay, if the fan turns up when running CPU-heavy computations. But I cannot have the GPU alone adding substantial noise already at baseline levels. Therefore, I want to make sure that I pick the right hardware this time.

I can choose between two models. The first device has a *4 GB NVIDIA T500* and *Intel Iris Xe Graphics* built in. The second one entails a *2 GB NVIDIA GeForce MX450* and *Intel Iris Xe Graphics*. Which of the two alternatives is likely to be the quieter solution?

Answer (score 2):

As far as my simple research goes, you should pick the thickest one. Thick laptops have more room for cooling and will be quieter. Both have the same tdp range (18-25W) so the level of quietness is for the best cooling solution

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say on basic specifications alone. the idea Irsu85 brought up is a good one, but for all we know the thinner one might use fancy cooling mechanisms like vapor chambers, has more/larger heat pipes or has an aluminum unibody that assists in dissipating more heat.
If you have the make and model. Try looking for video reviews. Often times they mention noise levels and they usually add the actual audio. Even if one might be slightly louder than the other if one is whiney and the other a hum. The whining one might get on your nerves earlier.